# Golang MGO driver with mongo atlas version 5 or above

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Currently, most of my production is based on microservices, and the majority of the services have already been upgraded to the official MongoDB driver. However, with the end-of-life for version 4.X approaching on 29/02/2024, I'm concerned that my team may not be able to upgrade all services to the official MongoDB driver by that time.

I would like to inquire if upgrading MongoDB Atlas to version 5.0 will allow services using the MGO driver to function normally. Thank you.

P.S. I have tested connecting to a MongoDB Atlas test cluster with version 5.0 using the MGO driver, and the connection was successful. However, I'm unsure if it will work seamlessly with all CRUD or aggregation operations.

Comment: And that is why integration tests are of utmost importance. There is no nice way to say it: You are in deep poo. Writing ITs probably is your best bet.